# proof by natural deduction without premises

Tags: natural-deduction, logic-translation

I'm currently stuck on this question:

> "Henry never wears his jacket and tie together at the same time. I.e. when Henry is dressed, he either doesn't wear his jacket, or he doesn't wear his tie, (or neither of the two items)."
>
> Formalize the reasoning as a statement logic sequence by using the following variables:
>
> - $k$: "Henry wears his jacket."
> - $f$: "Henry wears his tie."
>
> Prove the sequence using natural deduction.

I think the sequence would look like this:
$$\vdash \neg(k \land f)$$
But how do I prove this? Is it even possible without any premises?

Comment: Hint: what were the steps you informally used to reach that conclusion. Maybe they could be premise 1 and premise 2?

Comment: Do you mean that premise 1 would be: _k -> ¬f_ and that premise 2 would be: _f -> ¬k_ ? @TenO'Four

Comment: That works. It also works to disjoin the 3 possibilities they use in the description $((f\land\lnot k)\lor(\lnot f\land k))\lor(\lnot f\land\lnot k)$. The aim with these sorts of things isn't so much about proving anything, it's about translating what's being said as faithfully as you can. Now, the formula you've listed does follow from their description, and you can translate all of it. You can even translate, "if Henry is dressed, then it is the case that...", "it follows from this that if Henry is dressed then it is not the case that he is wearing his jacket and his tie".

Comment: Another point, is the first sentence in the description is the conclusion, the reason to accept the conclusion is given first :)

Comment: *given after, not "first

Comment: So, just to make things clear, this is the sequence I should try to prove : ((∧¬)∨(¬∧))∨(¬∧¬) ⊢ ¬(∧). Right? @TenO'Four

Comment: That would be my assessment, yes.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! :) @TenO'Four

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the exercise claims that it is specifying some reasoning instead of merely a claim, then I agree with Ten O'Four that the best guess is that they must be specifying an argument of the form "Conclusion, since Premise." (However, it is technically incorrect to interpret ‘I.e.,’—which starts the second sentence and is read “that is”—as “since”.)

**Premise**: when Henry is dressed, he either doesn't wear his jacket, or he doesn't wear his tie, (or he wears neither of the two items).

$$(\lnot k \land f) \lor (\lnot k \land \lnot f) \lor (k\land \lnot f) $$

**Conclusion**: Henry never wears his jacket and tie together at the same time.

$$\neg(k \land f)$$

Argue using disributive laws.

Comment: One part of the question is to prove the sequence by natural deduction. I'm sorry if I was unclear about that in my post. I'm very confused by that part since I can't find any premises to use in the proof. @Ryan

Comment: Yes, I've read the question multiple times but I can't seem to get any wiser. I've encountered sequences like _ ⊢ q -> (p -> (p-> (q->p) ) )_ without any premises. I've been able to prove those with natural deduction so i figured that this problem would result in something similar, but I'm not getting anywhere. @Ryan

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! @Ryan

Comment: @yzarc I've revised and expanded my answer in light of your Question revision.